# Print a class's report in other class's form view of OpenERP

Tags: report, odoo

There's only sale order's reports in the right of sale order's form view . how to add other class , for example product's reports into this form view ? And it will print the report of the product of the sale order .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create new module for that follow these steps,

create one folder which is your module give module name
for eg. demo_report

this folder contain :

1) demo_report/`__init__`.py file

```
import report
```

2) demo_report/`__openerp__`.py

```
{
    "name": "demo report",
    "version": "1.0",
    "depends": ["sale"],
    "author": "Serpent Consulting Services",
    "category": "Testing",
    "description": """
    This module provide :
    cr
    """,
    'update_xml': [],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install':False,
```

}

3) demo_report/demo_rep_view.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<openerp>
   <data>
   <report id="sale_order_product_id"
            string="Product Report"
            model="sale.order" 
            name="sale.order.product"
            rml="addons/demo_report/report/sale_order_product_report.rml"
            auto="True"
            />
  </data>
</openerp>
```

4) folder named report will contain your sale_order_product_detail.rml and product.py files.

5) demo_report/report/product.py ::

```
from report import report_sxw

class sale_order_product(report_sxw.rml_parse):



    def `__init__`(self,cr,uid,name,context):
        super(sale_order_product,self).__init__(cr,uid,name,context=context)


   report_sxw.report_sxw('report.sale.order.product','sale.order',
  'addons/demo_report/report/sale_order_product_detail.rml',parser=sale_order_product)
```

6) demo_report/report/`__init__`.py file

```
import product
```

7)  demo_report/report/sale_order_product_detail.rml

Define it as per your requirement.
In rml you can set the  all product detail by sale.order object easily as per your requirement.

This would helps you..

If any problem regarding that than let me Know

Regards,

Anil Kesariya

Comment: Thank u very much . How about the .rml has exists in "addons\product" floder ?

Comment: you have to create your own rml file under report folder

Comment: Thanks Dale for making perfect my answer.

Answer (score 0):

On my system `/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/sale/sale_report.xml` describes the sale/reports. You might start there to add new reports.

Comment: I know how to add the report of sale order . But how to add the reports of other class ?